# How do I create a mock using reflection with parameters using Moq?

Tags: c#, reflection, moq

I am trying to build a Generic testbuilder for generating objects, that i want to use in tests. One of the things I want to create is Mock implementations of interfaces. I want these Mocks to have Strict mockbehaviour, and the only way to set that afaik is by constructor parameter. I am using this code to create my interface mock:

```
public object Build(Type type)
{
    if (type.IsInterface)
    {
       List<object> mockParameters = new List<object>();
       mockParameters.Add(MockBehavior.Strict);
       Mock mock = (Mock)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Mock<>).MakeGenericType(type), mockParameters);
       return mock.Object;
    }
}
```

This  gives me an ArgumentException: Constructor arguments cannot be passed for interface mocks.
How can i set MockBehavior.Strict on my mock created with reflection?

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be greatly simplified to this:

```
public T Build()
{
    if (typeof(T).IsInterface)
    {
       return new Mock<T>(MockBehavior.Strict).Object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see that in this instance I could certainly do that. However, i also need to create it from the type only. (I edited the question to emphasise this)

Comment: @JesperKihlberg: Unfortunately, I never used Moq, but the exception you are getting seems pretty obvious: You can't create a strict Mock from an interface...